# Recording video using GPUImage twith two filters chained

Tags: ios, gpuimage

I am using GPUImage for recording video. I have two filters 1. Sepia filter and second one OverlayBlendFilter. with which filter I need to add GPUImageMovieWritter object?

Currently I done like,

```
filter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];

blendFilter = [[GPUImageOverlayFilter alloc] init]; 

[blendFilter addTarget : videoFilterView];

[element addTarget :blendFilter];

[blendFilter adTarget: movieWritter];

[filter addTarget: blendFilter];

[captureDevice addTaget:filter];

[captureDevice startCapture];

[movieWritter startRecoding];
```

Comment: Hi, any progress with this one? I'm currently stuck right now. I have two filters that needs update simultaneously. I have a brightness slider and a crop slider on my app. what I did was add chaining like what you did but currently what is seen on my view is the brightness filter being updated.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265292/how-to-achieve-those-filter-chaining-with-gpuimage-framework this helped me figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Check all samples. One sample explaining chaining filters.