# Chaining filters with GPUImage in swift

Tags: ios, swift, gpuimage

(First post to Stack Overflow - So, Hi 'waves nervously')

I'm using the GPUImage library with some success - and have managed to get a simple filter working on a static image using swift.

However I'm having problems trying to chain multiple filters together. The included examples in the library don't seem to cover this. There are plenty of objective C examples but not swift.

Can anyone please give an example of how to apply:

2 blend filters plus a brightness, contrast and saturation filter to a single static image?

I think this is sufficiently complex to cover most uses of the library in Swift. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried rewriting these Objective-C examples in Swift? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: To be fair the examples don't seem to cover chaining in any particular depth that I could find. (I don't understand Objective c syntax particularly well so excuse me if i'm missing something). (the 'simple' examples are here: https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/tree/master/examples/iOS ) I've tried Googling around quite a bit for swift examples without much luck. I think I understand the theory of chaining (I managed with coreimage), just the translation of syntax from obj-c to swift is confusing me with this library. I've been trying for days and hence resorting for a shout for help. Tnx

Comment: I think the best example I found for obj-c was on Stack Overflow here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265292/how-to-achieve-those-filter-chaining-with-gpuimage-framework

However I think this is out of date as its over a year old now.

Comment: I don't think it's out of date. Objective-C hasn't changed that much since *last year*, I don't know if GPUImage has, but I doubt so. As you're new on Stack Overflow, you may not know that "write code for me" questions are often frowned upon here. Try to do something yourself, and if you get stuck, show us what have you achieved so far and what is the specific problem you can't solve. This way you'll learn something and at the same time you'll more likely get a good answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Allocating and chaining filters in Swift is the same as it is in Objective-C, it's just syntactic conversion. For example, the following is how you'd chain two still image inputs to a blend filter in Objective-C, then have the result of that blend be directed to a contrast filter, with a capture of your final image:

```
GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter alloc] init];
[stillImageSource1 addTarget:blendFilter];
[stillImageSource2 addTarget:blendFilter];

GPUImageContrastFilter *contrastFilter = [[GPUImageContrastFilter alloc] init];
[blendFilter addTarget:contrastFilter];

[contrastFilter useNextFrameForImageCapture];
[stillImageSource1 processImage];
[stillImageSource2 processImage];

UIImage *currentFilteredImage = [contrastFilter imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

This is the equivalent in Swift:

```
let blendFilter = GPUImageOverlayBlendFilter()
stillImageSource1.addTarget(blendFilter)
stillImageSource2.addTarget(blendFilter)

let contrastFilter = GPUImageContrastFilter()
blendFilter.addTarget(contrastFilter)

contrastFilter.useNextFrameForImageCapture()
stillImageSource1.processImage()
stillImageSource2.processImage()

let currentFilteredImage = contrastFilter.imageFromCurrentFramebuffer()
```

As you can see, it's all syntax, nothing different in how you actually call things. You can use the Objective-C example code as a basis for what you want to do, and just rewrite that in your Swift equivalents. The Swift examples that I ship with the framework are either really simple (the tiny application that uses a single filter on live video) or fairly complex (my test case application that executes every filter and operation in the framework).

Comment: Thats great thanks. You are right it was just a syntax issue like you say. Objective C isn't the clearest language to me (yet) and its a bit like an english speaker trying to learn French using a German textbook :)

Answer (score 1):

When you use the FilterOperations.swift class from the demo, then you could initialize filters like this:

```
// Quick reference to the used filter configurations
var filterExposure = filterOperations.firstMatch {item in return item.listName == "Exposure"}!
var filterHighlightShadow = filterOperations.firstMatch {item in return item.listName == "Highlights and shadows"}!
var filterSaturation = filterOperations.firstMatch {item in return item.listName == "Saturation"}!
var filterContrast  = filterOperations.firstMatch {item in return item.listName == "Contrast"}!
var filterAdaptiveThreshold  = filterOperations.firstMatch {item in return item.listName == "Adaptive threshold"}!
```

And then setup these filters like this:

```
    (self.filterExposure.filter as GPUImageExposureFilter).exposure = 0.8 // -10 - 10
    (self.filterHighlightShadow.filter as GPUImageHighlightShadowFilter).highlights = 1.0 // 0 - 1
    (self.filterSaturation.filter as GPUImageSaturationFilter).saturation = 0.0 // 0 - 2
    (self.filterContrast.filter as GPUImageContrastFilter).contrast = 2.0  // 0 - 4
    (self.filterAdaptiveThreshold.filter as GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter).blurRadiusInPixels = 8.0
```

And then you could chain the filters like this:

```
    videoCamera.addTarget((self.filterExposure.filter as GPUImageInput))
    self.filterExposure.filter.addTarget((self.filterHighlightShadow.filter as GPUImageInput))
    self.filterHighlightShadow.filter.addTarget((self.filterSaturation.filter as GPUImageInput))
    self.filterSaturation.filter.addTarget((self.filterContrast.filter as GPUImageInput))
    self.filterContrast.filter.addTarget((self.filterAdaptiveThreshold.filter as GPUImageInput))
    self.filterAdaptiveThreshold.filter.addTarget(self.filterView)
```

Comment: I would highly recommend not using the data types I create in the FilterShowcaseSwift sample application. Those were only created just for that application as a means of organizing and presenting my test cases for that project alone. Use the classes directly, as I describe in my answer.